# array indexing in N1QL

Tags: json, couchbase, sql++

I ran this query: `SELECT z FROM data x UNNEST x.m2 y UNNEST y.country z;`
on this json document:

```
{
  "data": {
    "country": [
    { "name": "Canada" },
    { "name": "Greece" }
    ]
  }
}
```

And got this result:

```
[
  {
    "z": {
      "name": "Canada"
    }
  },
  {
    "z": {
      "name": "Greece"
   }
  }
]
```

I want to select the first country name (Canada) and tried doing this:

`SELECT z[0] FROM data x UNNEST x.m2 y UNNEST y.country z;`

but that just return empty results. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: I don't see m2 in your data.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring m2, do:

```
SELECT z
FROM data x UNNEST x.data y UNNEST y.country z
LIMIT 1;
```